# Проблемы с установкой Qt. Сборка из исходников на windows 10

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Собираю Qt из исходников, следуя инструкциям с https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#Getting_the_source_code
Использую Win 10, 64-bit. MinGW 8.1.0
Успешно склонировал себе репозиторий, на этапе выполнения configure, а именно команды (cmd):

```
C:\Qt_dir\qt5\qtbase\configure.bat -top-level -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

выводится:

```
Bootstrapping qmake ...
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'C:/Qt_dir/qt5/qtbase/qmake/Makefile.unix', needed by 'Makefile'.  Stop.
```

и все. В qtbase/qmake есть Makefile.unix, для чтения-записи доступен. 
Подскажите, в чем проблема, как мне завершить установку qt?

Comment: чтобы завершить установку qt нужно прочитать весь текст по вашей ссылке

Comment: АПД: проблему так и не устранил, забил и скачал установщик с открытой лицензией. Так легче